# Collection Serialization with Kryo

Tags: serialization, kryo

I'm trying to use [kryo](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/kryo) to serialize and deserialize a java collection.

The serializetion method looks like this:

```
public <T> byte[] serialize(List<T> objectsToSerialize) {
CollectionSerializer cs = new CollectionSerializer();
Output output = new Output();
cs.write(kryo, output, objectsToSerialize);
return output.toBytes();
}
```

Now I would like to write the deserialization method but having trouble doing so. Basically the CollectionSerializer has a read method, but I can't understand how to use it (and the documentation is pretty poor as far as I can tell).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to just serialize a `Collection` to a file then the standard Kryo commands (such as `kryo.writeClassAndObject`) can handle that very adequately. For example the following program passes a collection of strings to the file "testfile" and back again

```
public class TestClass{


    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
        serialize();
        deSerialize();
    }

    public static void serialize() throws FileNotFoundException{
        Collection<String>collection=new ArrayList<>();

        collection.add("This is a serialized collection of strings");

        Kryo kryo = new Kryo();
        Output output = new Output(new FileOutputStream("testfile"));
        kryo.writeClassAndObject(output, collection);
        output.close();
    }

    public static void deSerialize() throws FileNotFoundException{
        Collection<String>collection;

        Kryo kryo = new Kryo();
        Input input = new Input(new FileInputStream("testfile"));
        collection=(Collection<String>)kryo.readClassAndObject(input);
        input.close();

        for(String string: collection){
            System.out.println(string);
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: How does deSerialize() know what's the Class's structure (in case this is not a collection of Strings)

Comment: #Omri WriteClassAndObject (unlike WriteObject) adds a small amount of meta data in front of the object so kryo knows what to deserialise it to. Of course when casting you cast it to the most general type that it could be; so if it could be any collection you would cast to (Collection)

Comment: got 
com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoException: Encountered unregistered class ID: 1811647497
when trying to deserialize List<MyObject> collection